# How to disable drag to select in RecyclerView SelectionTracker?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to disable the drag to select feature of `RecyclerView` selection tracker. Currently after long press item gets selected and if I continue dragging continuous items are selected. I need to ensure that rest items are not selected.

Tried working something with the inbuild implementations but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3):

In your `SelectionTracker.Builder` there is a method `withSelectionPredicate(SelectionPredicate)`. You can define your own [`SelectionPredicate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/selection/SelectionTracker.SelectionPredicate) and implement its abstract method `canSelectMultiple` to return `false` - with this you will be able to select only the single item.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do want to select multiple items in a list. Just not select when I drag.

Comment: So maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42559801/9248201) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54434032/9248201) may help you. These two describe multi select with dragging, but maybe the solution to your issue is something similar.